# How to extract the loadings as a matrix from princomp() in R

Tags: r, loading, pca

In using princomp() I get an object with a "loadings" attribute.  The "loadings" is a composite object which holds information that I would prefer to have it separate in normal matrix format so that I can handle and manipulate it freely.  In particular I would like to extract the loadings in a matrix format.  I can not find a way to extract though this information from the object.  Is this possible and if yes how?

I want to use princomp() because it accepts as input a covariance matrix which is easier to provide since my dataset is very large (7000000 x 650).

For a reproducible example, please see below:

```
> data(mtcars)
> 
> princomp_mtcars = princomp(mtcars)
> 
> loadings = princomp_mtcars$loadings
> 
> names(loadings)
NULL
> 
> class(loadings)
[1] "loadings"
> 
> loadings

Loadings:
     Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 Comp.7 Comp.8 Comp.9 Comp.10 Comp.11
mpg                 0.982                0.144                                     
cyl                        0.228 -0.239  0.794  0.425  0.189         0.132   0.145 
disp -0.900 -0.435                                                                 
hp   -0.435  0.899                                                                 
drat                              0.133 -0.227         0.939         0.184         
wt                        -0.128  0.244  0.127 -0.187 -0.156  0.391  0.830         
qsec                      -0.886  0.214  0.190  0.255  0.103        -0.204         
vs                        -0.177        -0.103               -0.684  0.303   0.626 
am                         0.136        -0.205  0.201         0.572 -0.163   0.733 
gear                       0.130  0.276 -0.335  0.802 -0.217 -0.156  0.204  -0.191 
carb               -0.103  0.269  0.855  0.284 -0.165        -0.128 -0.240         

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 Comp.7 Comp.8 Comp.9 Comp.10 Comp.11
SS loadings     1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000   1.000   1.000
Proportion Var  0.091  0.091  0.091  0.091  0.091  0.091  0.091  0.091  0.091   0.091   0.091
Cumulative Var  0.091  0.182  0.273  0.364  0.455  0.545  0.636  0.727  0.818   0.909   1.000
>
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `l <- loadings; class(l) <- "matrix"; l`. I've made a copy and altered the copy in order to keep the original, if you further need it.

Comment: you can extract using `loadings(princomp_mtcars)` , and to explicitely convert to a matrix use `[]` ie `loadings(princomp_mtcars)[]` (although I think it is actually a matrix without explicitly converting, and `[]` just changes the print method)